# Apache kills long time running process

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, sigkill, mod-php

On linux apache server ( ubuntu 14.04 lts, apache 2.4.7 with mpm_prefork and mod_php) I have PHP scripts that takes a long time. These are killed by apache.

We have tune php setting (max_execution_time, set_time_limit...)

We haven't any trace in log (syslog, apache access/error log)

We have traced apache process with strace :

```
2172 is the script process
1939 is the apache main process
....

2172  14:53:01 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
1939  14:53:01 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=2172, si_status=SIGKILL, si_utime=3067, si_stime=38} ---
```

Comment: I suggest long running php scripts should be run in the background (not in the web-server) and should 'leave clues' in a database as to the 'state' of progress. This can be reported in the web-browser in a 'user-friendly' way.

Answer (score 1):

try set `ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);`
or run this script as root, then apache won't kill him

Comment: We have try max_execution_time -1 but same result.
And run script as root on bash... the script was not killed.

Comment: 20-30 minutes it depend on processing

Apache kill the script randomly. 2 min, 10 min , 15 min... 
An in few case script isn't killed

Comment: try: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Comment: KEEP ALIVE is on ? in configuration ?

Comment: yes :
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500 (test with 100)
KeepAliveTimeout 3 (test with 5)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is Apache2 is killing the process because it's not sent anything back for a certain amount of time. This often happens on shared hosting. If you're using output buffering, turn that off. Then every so often print out something and immediately use `flush()` to send the information back to Apache.

For example; in your longest loop you can do the following:

```
$time = time();
while($looping) {
  ... Code here ...
  if(time() > $time) {
    echo '.';
    flush();
    //ob_flush();//If you're using output buffering (often on by default)
    $time = time();
  }
}
```

Comment: we try with this in while :
                echo "<br>";
                echo memory_get_usage();
                flush();
                ob_flush();
                $cpt=0;

Comment: That should work. Also try using `set_time_limit(30)`, which will increase the time the script has to run by 30s